# Graphing the result of NSolve

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, plot

I'm trying to plot a parametric equation that was partially obtained using NSolve. Here's my attempted code:

```
VolumeDiff[v_] = 1.7 - v
SolveR[ v_] = 
 Re[NSolve[16 v^2 - 16 v*(r^3) + 3 (r^2) + 1 == 0, r, Reals]]
EnergyPos[r_] = r/2 (r + Sqrt[r^2 - 1])
EnergyNet[r_] = EnergyPos[SolveR[r]] + EnergyPos[SolveR[VolumeDiff[r]]]
ParametricPlot[{Re[EnergyNet[x]], 1.7 - 2. x}, {x, .1, 1.6}]
```

Basically, I have a cubic with two variables, I solve for one given the other and try to plot two parametric equations based on that original given variable. This is supposed to be a graph of energy vs. volume difference of two bubbles attached together. However, my axis are blank. I used NSolve to isolate the real root of the cubic equation and I guess Mathematica has a problem graphing with NSolve involved. I looked all over the internet but I couldn't find any answers to this. thanks for any help!
David

Comment: You can make some progress changing the definition `SolveR[v_?NumericQ] := 
 NSolve[16 v^2 - 16 v*(r^3) + 3 (r^2) + 1 == 0, r, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]`. The outer `Re[]` seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't have Re[] before but I figured it wouldn't hurt when trying to graph the real part of the answer. If you don't mind my asking, what does the [[1,1,2]] do at the end there?

Comment: It picks the first solution, as your equation is quadratic.

Comment: @b.gatessucks The equation is cubic as far as I see, with only one real root in the interval of interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several errors corrected.
You should read about how `SetDelayed ( := )`  and `Solve[]` work.

```
VolumeDiff[v_] := 1.7 - v
SolveR[v_] := NSolve[16 v^2 - 16 v*(r^3) + 3 (r^2) + 1 == 0, r, Reals][[1]]
EnergyPos[r_] := r/2 (r + Sqrt[r^2 - 1])
EnergyNet[r_] := EnergyPos[r /. SolveR[r]]+EnergyPos[r /. SolveR[VolumeDiff[r]]]
ParametricPlot[{EnergyNet[x], 1.7 - 2. x}, {x, .1, 2}]
```

[image]